# Unable to run java console app using codenvy SDK

Tags: java, eclipse, codenvy

I installed codenvy SDK in my linux machine from github:
https://github.com/codenvy/sdk

After starting the server localhost:8080

I tried to run the simple hello java console application.

But when I run this app, I am getting the following error. Can someone please help?

"Runner environment 'system:/java/standalone/simple/cli' is not available for workspace '1q2w3e' on infra 'community'."

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Codenvy SDK does not support console app, only web-apps. To support different types of applications in the SDK docker can be used. But I don't know how to use it in SDK.
By the way you can use hosted version of [Codenvy](https://codenvy.com) which support console apps (will be started in the docker.) You should not configure docker to use it, but custom receipts are supported too.
[Here](https://codenvy.com/f?id=dvu3a7kgegbuads2) is console hello world app created in my workspace with Codenvy wizard.
This URL is factory - feature that allow to share projects easily. To copy this project to your workspace click "Persist" button on the top of IDE. Or create your own with a project wizard.

Comment: the referenced project does not load for me (it says _Unable to import source of project. fatal: unable to access ' https://codenvy.com/git/f5/fc/9d/workspaceu0bweg86xntphvwg/java-console/ ': The requested URL returned error: 500_). I suppose you deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Console apps already supported in cloud version, while there are some problems with Eclipse plugin and as you ran into with Codenvy SDK (Eclipse Che)

Raise an issue at codenvy SDK and/or ask on forum https://groups.google.com/a/codenvy.com/forum/#!forum/codenvy

Don't forget to reference this question.